# After upgrade to SQL Server 2008, database log file grows disproportionaly

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

After upgrading from SQL2005 to 2008 SP1, we're suddenly observing disproportional expansions of the database log file during large transactions.

Example: inserting 75 million rows into table B, deleting those same 75M rows from table A, both in the same transaction. Total amount of data about 2 times 20GB, but database log file grows to 150GB and beyond.

Never seen this in SQL2005, before upgrading.

I couldn't find this documented as a known regression in SQL2008 anywhere.. anyone seen this, too?

Thanks

Max

Comment: Did your level of recovery change?

Comment: No.. simple recovery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use fn_dblog() to analyze the log content and understand where does the increase come from. With simple recovery, the log might roll over and not be able to analyze, so for analysis purposes I'd recommend changing recovery to full, taking a dummy full backup to /dev/nul (`backup database ... to disk='nul:'`) and re-running your transaction. If possible, mark down the transaction ID (look in [`sys.dm_tran_active_transactions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174302.aspx)) then look into the `select ... from fn_dblog(null, null) where [TransactionID] = 'xactid'` output and see what kind of records are generated so your log grows to 150Gb. The Reserved space is the relevant column for you. Eventually, if possible, compare with same on SQL 2005.

After that, you can revert the recovery model back to simple. Note though that the log reservation behavior might be different under simple than under full, but we'll cross that bridge when we get to it if it happens.

Comment: You could also analyse the log backup with this

http://www.apexsql.com/

there is a free trial and not to difficult to use. There is a guide/review here too 

http://www.sql-server-performance.com/software/review/apex_log_p1.aspx

There are other tools that do the same but I couldn't find one with a free trial last time I needed to do this (about 4 months ago)

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

[A transaction log grows unexpectedly or becomes full on a computer that is running SQL Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317375)

This is for SQL 2005, but may also be relevant to 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Your transaction log may be set to auto-grow.  Turn that setting off and set your log file at a fixed size.

Answer (score -2):

This is because your log file is logging everything, what i would recommend is trimming the database log files via the [Shrink database task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141819.aspx). Remember to do that after you have done a backup.

Tsql to do it:

```
USE [N2CMS]
GO
DBCC SHRINKDATABASE(N'MyDataBase', 10, TRUNCATEONLY)
```

Depending on how you take backups, your backup software should be able to do this

Comment: In case you wonder why you get downvotes: http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/post/Auto-shrink-e28093-turn-it-OFF!.aspx

Comment: So you run the task that either rebuild index, or defrag it. I stand by my reply, but thanks for letting me know why you down vote it.